# Is there a function to find color of point in AWT/SWING

Tags: java, swing, awt

So, I've created this little maze building algorithm (trying to understand how Java AWT & Swing works).

Now, I've used the Graphics (paint method) to create the maze itself, meaning I didn't store it anywhere.
Now I wanted to know if there is a way to know if at given a specific point on the JFrame, is there a way to tell which color it is?
If so, how can I do it?
Let's say for example in my maze I want to see what color is on the PURPLE dot (seeing if it's a wall there basically).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfQon.png]

Is there a way to do it, or do I have to do a work-around that?

Thanks.

Comment: You should use paintComponent() rather than paint().

Comment: *"Now, I've used the Graphics (paint method) to create the maze itself, meaning I didn't store it anywhere."* While that may apply to the graphic itself, the code should have access to the logic which created the graphics, or better, a 'data model' that represents it. Here my data model would include the maze as `Shape` instances and use `Shape.contains(Point)` once clicked (or whatever it is that produces the `Point`). What is being attempted here with getting colors, is an unnecessary hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to a `Component`'s image buffer. But there are two indirect ways.

1. (Better) Create an Image (Either BufferedImage or Component.createImage) with the same height and width as your Component. You can then run `myComponent.paint(myBuffer.getGraphics());`. This will draw the component on the image, and from there you can get the pixel `Color` you are interested in
2. (Alternative) You can use java.awt.Robot to capture the screen in an Image. Use this image similar as described above